# Shows only one VEVENT (first) from many in .ics file

Tags: icalendar

Here is the ICS file content:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Test//Test 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Tokyo
X-LIC-LOCATION:Asia/Tokyo
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20190108T154626
UID:a0K1I000007ljAxUAI-a0D1I000007daO4UAI
RELATED-TO:a0K1I000007ljAxUAI
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20190123T080000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20190123T200000
SUMMARY:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2
LOCATION:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2
DESCRIPTION:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20190108T154626
UID:a0K1I000007ljAxUAI-a0D1I000007daNzUAI
RELATED-TO:a0K1I000007ljAxUAI
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20190110T080000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20190110T200000
SUMMARY:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1
LOCATION:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1
DESCRIPTION:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

In Thunderbird and Gmail I able to see only first (by order) event. Is this normal behaviour for mail clients, should I create separate .ics file for each VEVENT then and send it with single mail? Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing. Did you find a solution? (re: sending multiple events in one .ics file)

Comment: Same problem here (still).  Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Separate them.   I don't know a calendar app that allows one to 'invite' someone to multiple events at the same time. One can of course send a multi event file and ask the user to import it (but for multi events sometimes subscribe is better).  If one sends an ics file generated by google calendar, it does the same thing (along with option to download ics file), so nothing to do with your file.

If the need is to have a person see multiple events at a time, a better approach would be to offer them a personal subscribeable ics url.   That way they see it separately in their calendar app and it will update/refresh when there are changes.

Comment: The standard allows multiple VEVENT objects, so I don't see why sending multiple events in one file is inferior to setting up a server with URL and sharing that one. Clearly the first approach would be easier. And btw: the ubuntu calendar app imports both events fine.